# Commerce: Template error: “Variable "option" does not exist

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am getting this error when trying to send a confirmation email to the user.

```
Template error: “Variable "option" does not exist
```

If I remove every bit of markup from my email template, and literally only have `<p>Hello World</p>` I get an email.

I am able to click the "Download Receipt" link, and everything works great.

When I output the `option` variable: `{{ option }}`:
When I click on the "Download" link, I see `receipt`.

I am using the default template that ships with commerce, with the addition of a jpg header image. At the bottom of the template is this:

```
...
{% endset %}

{# Use the option param passed into the pdf template to show different 
   order pdf's depending on the context #}

 {% switch option %}
 {% case "receipt" %}
    <h1>Receipt for Order #{{ order.number[:7] }}</h1>
    {{ orderTable }}
{% case "ajax" %}
    <h1>NA</h1>
{% default %}
    {{ orderTable }}
{% endswitch %}
</body>
```

So clearly it has something to do with `option` not getting set. I'm not sure where I might have un-done setting that variable.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `option` variable is only available in the pdf template, it is not available in the email template.

`order` variable available in both.

Comment: Ok it's got to be a variable I've added somewhere else. Thanks Luke!